# Python, GCC causes installation of module to fail

Tags: python, gcc, easy-install

Each time I try to install a Python module (via easy_install or python setup.py install), the installation fails with:

```
    unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Help Me

System: Mac OSX running Lion with XCode 4 installed

Update: here is the output when trying to install pygame:

```
    familys-imac:~ Paul-Arthur$ easy_install pygame
    Searching for pygame
    Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pygame/
    Reading http://www.pygame.org/
    Reading http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
    Best match: pygame 1.9.1release
    Downloading http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release.zip
    Processing pygame-1.9.1release.zip
    Running pygame-1.9.1release/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/y7/wskjhyr55_sg4n0w7c8qvrpm0000gp/T/easy_install-tioF5H/pygame-1.9.1release/egg-dist-tmp-gxSl_1


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
    Using Darwin configuration...

    Hunting dependencies...
    Framework SDL found
    Framework SDL_ttf found
    Framework SDL_image found
    Framework SDL_mixer found
    Framework smpeg not found
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : found
    SCRAP   : not found
    PORTMIDI: not found
    Framework CoreMidi found

    If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
    the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


    Continuing With "setup.py"
    warning: no files found matching 'readme.txt'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/CVS'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/CVS'
    unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
    error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Please mention on which platform you are trying to build. It looks like you are trying to compile under windows. gcc-4.0 is the 64 bit gcc cygwin build. Normally that should be bundled with cygwin's default installation. So it might be that you need to install cygwin which is missing from your platform.

Comment: Do you have the GCC (the compiler toolkit) actually installed? On Mac OS X you'll need the Developer Tools (or homebrew) - on Debian-ish Linux systems you'll need to `apt-get install gcc`.

Comment: updated with system info